# Fatal error due to composer.json in slim tree framework

Tags: php, slim, composer-php

I have been following [Alex Gareth's tutorial on building a shopping cart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GL5pG1Sx-oc).
I am stock because I think that the **composer.json** isn't autoloading my files correctly.
Here is my error :

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Order\App' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\order\bootstrap\app.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\order\public\index.php(3): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\order\bootstrap\app.php on line 10"

**composer.json file**

```
    {
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.0",
        "slim/twig-view": "^2.4",
        "php-di/slim-bridge": "^2.0",
        "illuminate/database": "^5.6"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Order\\": "Order"
        }
    }
}
```

**App class**

```
    namespace Order;

    use DI\ContainerBuilder;
    use DI\Bridge\Slim\App as DIBridge;

    class App extends DIBridge{

        protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $builder){
            $builder->addDefinitions([
                'settings.displayErrorDetails' => true
            ]);

            //
        }

}
```

**app.php** file which is the bootstrap file

```
<?php

use Order\App;

session_start();

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
//require __DIR__ . '/../app/App.php';

$app = new App;
```

If i un-comment the require line where i pulled in App.php it works fine.

Directory Structure:

[image: folder structure]

> OS : Windows 10

Comment: Can you please show us the file and folder structure of your app? Or at least for the above mentioned files and folders). Also, make sure that the files and folders have the correct casing. Many OS's are picky with that (except Windows). Example, if you have `Order\App`, the files must have the casing: `Order/App.php` while `order/app.php` will fail.

Comment: Let me try to write that (I am a beginner so pardon me)

order/ is my root dir
in order
    app [dir], Bootstrap[dir], public[dir], vendor[dir], composer.json, composer.lock
app[dir] >>> App.php
bootstrap[dir] >>> app.php
public[dir]>>> .htaccess, index.php
vendor[dir] >>> all framework files

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information (and where you can write a proper directory tree). Also include what OS you're on.

Comment: I've done so now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `autoload` to following:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Order\\": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: @cornelking also, rename dir `app` to `App`

Comment: @cornelking try to run `composer dumpautoload`

Answer (score 0):

You should change your autoload to target the `app/` folder instead, since there's where your `App.php` is located:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Order\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

What this essentially does is telling the autoloader that all classes that has the namespace `Order\` exists in `app/`.

So from now on, if you would create sub folders in `app/`:

```
app/
    App.php
    Foo/
        Bar.php
```

Then `Bar.php` should have the namespace `Order\Foo` and you would access that class with: `$bar = new Order\Foo\Bar()`.

**Note:** This is where the file/folder casing is important. The namespace casing and the class name *must* have the same casing as the files and folders. Otherwise, it will still work for you on Windows, but it will fail on other OS's (like linux).